# How do I set up a ThemeForest theme in a Django project?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I recently got started with Django, took a few courses on it and got the basic idea in terms of project structure, urls, templates, static files etc. To avoid learning frontend development (and build my app faster), I thought a bootstrap theme would be a good option. I got this https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469 which has bootstrap4 in the title, however, it seems that integrating it into the project is not as simple as placing the scss, js and vendor files into my static folder. The 'getting started' resources suggest that it runs on NodeJS, and has a whole backend of its own. I'm not asking for a bespoke full guide on how to do it, but it'd be nice to know if the two things are compatible or I if should move on and try some other frontend solution instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

They are "compatible", but you are probably better off starting with a theme that is just HTML/CSS/JS (not made for Angular, unless you are trying to use Angular with Django). I have actually used this exact theme in a Django project.

To start, just take components from the HTML and put them into Django template files. Generally, I would make a layout page which is something like this:

```
{% load static %}
<!-- templates/layout.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- include styles from metronic here -->
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Hope this helps a bit, good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I think I'll take your advice and start with a simpler theme.